# Internal anchor in TYPO3 doesn't work

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, typo3

Normally an internal anchor is defined with `<a name="anchorname">Introduction</a>`. If you link on to an anchor you write something like `<a href="#anchorname">Top</a>`.

TYPO3 adds before each element an anchor like `<a id="c118"></a>`. So now I link with the RTE on a content element (tab: page). If I click on such a link `<a class="internal-link" title="Some text" href="index.php?id=24#c118">Some text</a>` nothing happens in FF 15.0.1.

- FF 15.0.1 - not working (does nothing)
- IE9 - not working (jumps but to wrong position)
- Safari 5.1.7 - works
- Opera 12.02 - not working (does nothing)
- Chrome 21 - works

Are there any solutions to link to a content element on the same page in TYPO3? Is that outside the specification or a browser bug?

**Edit:**

Now I put this into the main setup:

```
tt_content.stdWrap {
  dataWrap = |
  prepend >
  prepend = COA
  prepend {
    10 = TEXT
    10.dataWrap = <a id="c{field:uid}" name="c{field:uid}"><!-- ANCHOR --></a>
    10.if.isFalse.field = _LOCALIZED_UID
    20 = TEXT
    20.dataWrap = <a id="c{field:_LOCALIZED_UID}" name="c{field:_LOCALIZED_UID}"><!-- ANCHOR --></a>
    20.if.isTrue.field = _LOCALIZED_UID
  }
  prefixComment = 1 | CONTENT ELEMENT,
uid:{field:_LOCALIZED_UID//field:uid}/{field:CType}
}
```

Now I have `<a id="c118" name="c118"></a>` anchors in the HTML code but FF still won't work ... Than I found out if I disable all styles (CSS), than the anchors work in FF. Why that?

**Solution:**

The following lines were the problem:

```
.gallery {
  /* Weird anchor link bug in browsers if activated 
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  */
  width:753px;
  margin-bottom:25px;
}
```

Remains the question why this causes problems ...

Answer (score 2):

Technically these anchors *should* be correct and *should* work. See **[w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3)**.
However, you can alter the generation of those anchors by modifying `tt_content.stdWrap.prepend.dataWrap` in the Typoscript setup. Use Typoscript Object Browser to check the current setting.

Comment: Currently I have the following value `<a id="c{field:_LOCALIZED_UID}"></a>`. Why are many browser struggling with this definition? Should I change to `<a name="c{field:_LOCALIZED_UID}"></a>`?

Comment: Try `<a id="c{field:_LOCALIZED_UID}" name="c{field:_LOCALIZED_UID}"></a>` as suggested in the document I mentioned.

Comment: See my updated question. I tried your approach but that didn't worked. If I disable CSS then the links are working ...

Comment: Try to validate your HMTL and CSS for any errors. I'm afraid though that without seeing all the code it's not really possible to help you.

Comment: I tried to remove the validation errors on a static file (saved copy of the original). The error stayed the same. Nevertheless, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Up to TYPO3 6.2.25 without any additional code, I have used:

```
<a name="top"></a>

<a href="/index.php?id=(id-number)#top">Go to Top</a>
```

Better solution I saw somewhere:

```
<a name="top"/>

<a href="" onclick="javascript:document.location.hash='top'; return false;">Goto top</a>
```